# Issue with jQuery usage in Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2, javascript, jquery

Currently I have a custom block loaded almost last on the page containing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test.js"></script>
```

This script is pretty much the usual stuff, just manipulating HTML of my product page.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
    {
      Do stuff with various HTML elements;
    }
  });
});
```

However, this method only seems to work as intended in Chrome. In Firefox, it just throws `jQuery not defined`, despite Magento 2 obviously having a local copy of jQuery called very early on the page.

Any ideas on how to get this working in Firefox? (Or better yet, how to do this properly, as I have a feeling I'm skirting round a lot of Magento's intended JS usage.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add js like that

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ $(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
    {
      Do stuff with various HTML elements;
    }
  });
}); });
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much, this had been driving me crazy.

Comment: There is a !domReady plugin included within the require implementation btw.

Comment: How to use the !domReady? window.load and document.ready seem to fire a bet prematurely for me

Comment: [ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui, 'domReady!'] is this all that is required for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom jquery function by:

```
 require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
      $(document).ready(function($) {
           alert("Hello"); //Do Your jQuery Code
      });
 });
```

Comment: i used as above in my module but some time it fails, can you please see once the below question

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220884/uncaught-typeerror-el-colorpicker-is-not-a-function-magento-2/220971#220971