# how to call custom jquery function on custom phtml in magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

I want to call a custom JS method `quickViewPopUp` like below on a `list.phtml` file in magento2. 
 How can i do it? I'm doing something like this.

```
<?php    
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>">
        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                                . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                        <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                        $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                   <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="quick_view">
                                    <button type="button" onclick="quickViewPopUp(this)" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" class="quick-view-btn-<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"><?php echo __('Quick-View') ?></button>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow()): ?>
                                        <a href="#"
                                           class="action towishlist"
                                           title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                           aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                           data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                           data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                           role="button">
                                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php
                                    $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');
                                    ?>
                                    <a href="#"
                                       class="action tocompare"
                                       title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                       role="button">
                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription): ?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
            }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<script>
    require(['jquery', "mage/mage"], function(jQuery){
    //<![CDATA[

    function quickViewPopUp(element) {
    console.log('ok');
    var baseUrl = '<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() ?>';
    var productId = jQuery(element).attr('data-id');    
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + "quickview",
    data: { prod_id: productId, call_type: "quickview"},
    success: function(data) {

    jQuery.fancybox(data, {
    fitToView: false,
    width: 905,
    height: 505,
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none'
    }); 
    }
    });
    }
    //]]>

    });



</script>
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102761/issue-with-jquery-usage-in-magento-2/102768#102768 check it this  is your solution

Answer (score 1):

### Links

[Use custom JS in M2 - Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html)

[Calling and initialising JS in M2 - Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html)

[How to use Knockout JS in Magento 2 - Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103861/how-to-use-knockout-js-within-magento-2/103889#103889)

### Reference the JS

The first step is to reference your JS file inside the PHTML template:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    // components initialized on the element defined by selector
    "<element_selector>": {
        "<js_component1>": ...,
        "<js_component2>": ...
    },
    // components initialized without binding to an element
    "*": {
        "<js_component3>": ...
    }
}
</script>
```

For example if you wanted to load `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/product/view/validation.js` when the dom element `#test` has loaded you would write:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#test": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                options-can-be-passed-here
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you don't care about making sure the node has been rendered then you can use `*` which will load the JS regardless of any DOM elements.

### Add your JS

In your JS file you will need to use the following structure:

```
define ([
    'jquery',
    'other/dependencies/can/go/here',
    `domReady!` // If you require your script to run after page load
], function ($, anotherFunction, domReady) {
    // Your code here
});
```

### Loading the new file

To load the file on the frontend you'll need to clear `pub/static/frontend`, `pub/static/_requirejs`, and `var/view_preprocessed`. Also clear your browser cache.

### Notes

I would highly recommend choosing this method over adding JS inside a template, I'm a big fan of separating the content and logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any script from template you want if you already register it in `requirejs-config`

```
<script type="text/javascript">require(['yourscript']);</script>
```

Comment: Would it not be better practice to load require JS via `x-magento-init` and have your script in it's own file? I feel that writing JS inside a PHTML template is not good practice.

Comment: Should i call js via data-mage-init way in template? avoid call js directly in phtml. Sometimes i don't need use jslayout or component to pass php to js

Comment: This way does work and the functionality should be the same so technically it doesn't matter which way you do it, it's more a case of splitting up the structure (PHTML) and the logic (JS) as most people find it easier to maintain.