# Uncaught TypeError: $el.ColorPicker is not a function Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, adminhtml, custom

**Magento ver. 2.0.18**

I created a custom module in backend there is color picker options.

for this i used this link [color picker](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137605/magento-2-1-1-how-to-add-color-picker-in-admin-configuration-options) answer of @EmizenTech

**it works perfectly but some time it gives** and if i refresh the page error gone, in network i can see the `jquery is loaded before the colorpicker.js`

```
 index):421 Uncaught TypeError: $el.ColorPicker is not a function
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):421)
        at fire (jquery.js:3232)
        at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
        at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
        at (index):416
        at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
        at Module.check (require.js:866)
        at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
        at require.js:132
        at require.js:1156
```

My `/var/www/html/magentoce20/app/code/Companyname/ModuleName/Block/Color.php`

```
<?php

namespace Companyname\ModuleName\Block;

class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
         require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) { 
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                    $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                    // Attach the color picker
                    $el.ColorPicker({
                        color: "'. $value .'",
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

My `/var/www/html/magentoce20/app/code/Companyname/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

My `/var/www/html/magentoce20/app/code/Companyname/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {

    deps: [
        "Companyname_ModuleName/js/main",
    ],


     map: {
        '*': {
            'slickjs': 'Companyname_ModuleName/js/slick/slick'

        }
    }

};
```

UPDATE : I just wrapped my `colorpicker` code in load so that html loads completely first and than js comes , i know require is doing same thing in magento 2 but currently this solves my issues.
               `$(window).load(function() {`

Comment: Sorry I reviewed example from core files and found out that alias is not needed.

Comment: I think you should look into whether you have included the library in your corresponding layout xml .

Comment: you are talking about `adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` i shared the code above

Answer (score 0):

Add the js file in head of `adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` too. Update following code in your layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
        <link src="jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: i read some where on SE that we should not include js directly in head and even if i included to check still problem is same that is some time error is thrown in console.

Comment: My extesnion is completed but stuck in QA just because of this , and i am not able to find any solution for this

Comment: can i wrap my color code in  `$(window).load(function() { }`

Comment: I don't think it will help, but there is no reason to not try.

Comment: This error come just because it loads before html is fully loaded I think, so is there any way to overcome other than . load ?

Comment: Require Js is for doing just that, also your code is already under document ready code , but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

**=> Add JavaScript color picker library in your layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
        <link src="jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**=> Create system.xml**

```
<config ...>
    <system>
        ...
        <section>
            ...
            <group id="my_color_group" ...>
                <field id="my_color_option" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Background Color</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Background color]]></comment>
                    <frontend_model>abc\Color\Block\Color</frontend_model> <!-- Our block for attaching color picker to text box -->
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**=> Create the block file:**

```
<?php
namespace abc\Color\Block;

class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $elementId = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                    $elementId.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                    $elementId.ColorPicker({
                        color: "'. $value .'",
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $elementId.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

Comment: @inrsaurabh check this solution it's 100% work.

Comment: @emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd , thank you for your efforts and the code, but there is no difference in your method and the one suggested by vivek-kumar even most of the link suggest same except few dont suggest to add js in layout i this way ,they ask to do so using require and second as the color picker is already available in Mage 2 core do we need to include the same in our extension i am bit confused by reading different articles.

Answer (score 0):

try it:-

Replace code

> path:-
> /var/www/html/magentoce20/app/code/Companyname/ModuleName/Block/Color.php

```
<?php

namespace Companyname\ModuleName\Block;

class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
         require(["jquery","Companyname_ModuleName/js/colorpicker"], function ($) { 
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                    $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                    // Attach the color picker
                    $el.ColorPicker({
                        color: "'. $value .'",
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```